# Django 2.2 - Context Processors fail to make global variable available in templates

Tags: python, django

I have a project named hotel including an app named utils where a context_processors.py file is created. This file includes an hotel function that takes a request in input and returns a dict as follows:

```
from hotel import settings

def hotel(request):

    return {
        'site_name': settings.SITE_NAME,
        'meta_keywords': settings.META_KEYWORDS,
        'meta_description': settings.META_DESCRIPTION,
        'phone_num': settings.PHONENUM,
        'contact_email': settings.EMAIL,
        'address': settings.ADDRESS,
        'request': request
    }
```

Of course settings.py include all these variables.
I then added the context_processors function in the TEMPLATES dict:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        ...
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                ....,
                'utils.context_processors.hotel'
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

I should a write the views.py (should I use render or render_to_response? How should I pass the context) to pass all the variables defined in the hotel function to the project templates, but i can not manage to pass the context values.

Comment: As far as I know you can access site_name and rest in every template without any other additional steps.

Comment: I solved by returning `render_to_response(template_name, locals())` in `views.py`